# javascript: what is two "new" operator doing?

Tags: javascript, new-operator

Encountered this code:

```
function Person() { }

Person.prototype.getName = function () {
  console.log('John')
}
```

When running below code in console

```
new new Person().getName()
```

it prints out

```
John
```

and returns

```
Person.getName {}
```

What is the order of the "two" operators? and why does it return such result?

Comment: May be, `Person.getName` returns an object?

Comment: @Soolie The definition of `.getName()` is in the question ;)

Comment: @Andreas Ah, alright...

Comment: `new Person()` instantiates a new object and uses `Person` as the constructor function. Then `new (person).getName()` instantiates a new object and uses `(person).getName()` as the constructor function.

Comment: thanks @deceze , so it turns out that "new new Person().getName()" equals "new Person.prototype.getName()"